# How to solve Fundamental Theorem of Homomorphisms problems

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

[image]

I found a video on youtube that shows how to use the fundamental theorem to solve these type of questions [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pal391yUoWE] and it says to use four steps, the first two being to define a map G->H that is a homomorphism. Where H is the set after the congruent/isomorphic symbol.  But I can't seem to create that for any of these problems.  Is there a different way of doing these problems?

Comment: It is also common to call this theorem the "first isomorphism theorem", for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Consider  the exponential form of non-zero complex numbers: $\;z=r\mathrm e^{i\theta}$, and the projections:
\begin{align}
\mathbf C^*&\longrightarrow \mathbf R^+,&\mathbf C^*&\longrightarrow \mathbf U,\\
z=r\,\mathrm e^{i\theta}&\longmapsto r,&z=r\,\mathrm e^{i\theta}&\longmapsto \mathrm e^{i\theta}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the first isomorphism theorem states:

> If $\varphi: G \to H$ is an onto homomorphism, then $G/\ker(\varphi) \cong H$.

Now let's look at a), in which $G = \Bbb C$ and $H = \Bbb R$.  As you've read, we should indeed be looking for a homomrphism from $\varphi: \Bbb C \to \Bbb R$, but that doesn't seem like a lot to go on.  What you should *also* pay attention to is the fact that the kernel should match up too.  In this case, we should have $\ker \varphi = U$.

Let's take that statement apart for a second.  In this case, we have 
$$
\ker \varphi = \varphi^{-1}(e_H) = \varphi^{-1}(1) = \{x \in \Bbb C: \varphi(x) = 1\}
$$
which means that for our map $\varphi$, we should have $\varphi(x) = 1 \iff x \in U$.  Now, what "natural" map from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb R$ is such that $\varphi(x) = 1$ exactly when $x$ is in the unit circle?

**Spoiler:**

> How about $\varphi(x) = |x|$?

Check that this map is indeed a homomorphism.  Since this function is a homomorphism is whose kernel is $U$, we can now use the fundamental theorem.

Now, try all this for b).  What "natural" map $\psi:\Bbb C \to U$ is such that $\psi(x) = 1$ whenever $x$ is a real number?  What's the natural way to take a complex number and "make it" a complex number with length $1$?

---

That second question is quite a bit trickier.  To construct the homomorphism you want, we can start by noting that every rational number can be written in the form
$$
q = 2^n\frac{a}{b}
$$
where both $a$ and $b$ are odd.  Define $\varphi(q) = n$.

Comment: Wait, you lost me.  how does φ(x)=|x| take a complex number and make it real?  Don't you just get back the positive version of whatever complex number you used?  Like the absolute value of -4-3i is 4+3i?  That's why I didn't use that.  I did try f(x+yi)=x, =x+y, =x^2+y^2, =x-y   nothing worked when I stuck them into φ(xy)=φ(x)φ(y) to prove the homomorphism.

Comment: That's not how $|x|$ works. You have $|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. In the complex plane, it's the distance from $0$.

Comment: Oh.  We are doing that in my Linear Algebra class right now.  We are using the notation ||x|| - the norm of x.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, you need a homomorphism $\varphi : G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ which has precisely all the roots of unity as kernel, i.e. $\varphi(u) = 1$ if and only if $u \in U$. An obvious candidate might be to take $\varphi(x) = |x|$ which is clearly a homomorphism that satisfies these properties.

If you want to do it differently, you will still have to provide a bijective homomorphism in one direction or the other. Since providing a homomorphism $G/U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ is at least as hard as providing a homomorphism $G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and since we assume there is a difficulty there, you could try to go in the other direction. You can define $f : \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow G/U$ which for example sends and $x$ to its class modulo $U$. Checking that this is a bijective homomorphism is not that hard. I advise you to make the first reasoning though, since it is used constantly in group theory (and commutative algebra, topology...)